# My code works when pasted into button but not from class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I was trying to put the code form a button into a class,  but during testing I noticed the panel on my form does not update. It works fine when setting the panel directly form a button(See buttons2's code).

button1 code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          SpecialPanelBuilder spb = new SpecialPanelBuilder();
          panel1 = spb.PopulatedPanel();

        }
```

Special Panel class...

```
public class SpecialPanelBuilder
    {
        public Panel PopulatedPanel()
        {
            Panel p = new Panel();
            Graphics g;

            int size = 30;
            int TextLeft = size;
            //int LeftStartBox = 


            g = p.CreateGraphics();

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("test"), new Font("Arial", size /2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft),
            (size) - (-2));

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, 300, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 300, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("test"), new Font("Arial", size / 2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft + 300),
            (size) - (-2));

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 600, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 600, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("test"), new Font("Arial", size/2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft + 600),
            (size) - (-2));

            return p;
    }
```

Button 2 code with all the code from the class this works...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            int size = 30;
            int TextLeft = size;
            //int LeftStartBox = 

            Graphics g;
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("Below Threshold"), new Font("Arial", size / 2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft),
            (size) - (-2));

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, 300, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 300, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("Less than 20% above threshold"), new Font("Arial", size / 2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft + 300),
            (size) - (-2));

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 600, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 600, 10, size, size);
            g.DrawString(("On Order"), new Font("Arial", size / 2, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            (size + TextLeft + 600),
            (size) - (-2));

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i'm not sure to be right but in the button 2 your graphic object g is set with the panel1.CreateGraphics(), which is not the case in the button1.Code. so you are actually using the graphics object of you inner panel variable.